# matlab GOTO (sort of)

Tags: matlab, debugging, interactive, goto

I have a long script calling many other scripts that spit out a lot of figures.

For debugging purposes I think it would be useful if -when clicking on a picture- the editor goes to a specific line. Does anyone know if this is possible?

I thought I could implement something like

```
A=[];
figure
plot(x)

A=ginput(1)

if A~=[]
  goto(pointer,line)
end
```

The problem is that it only would work only right after that the figure is made. Not at the end of the analysis when I take a look to the figures for eventual errors.

In other words: is there a way to go to a specific line of the code by clicking on a figure?

N.B. For an implementation of GOTO see ([GOTO FileExchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26949-matlab-goto-statement))

Comment: Why not just put labels in comments and then do a simple find (i.e. ctrl+f)  in the editor?

Comment: Looking for fanciness? xd 
Good comment of course.

Comment: Take a look at [callbacks](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/callbacks-programmed-response-to-user-action.html): "A callback is a function that executes in response to some predefined user action, such as clicking on a graphics object or closing a figure window."

Comment: One approach may be to separate the script into a separate function that returns true to do a specific action or false to proceed normally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the `opentoline` function in conjunction with a callback.  Something like

```
plot(1:10); % A simple plot
set(gcf,'ButtonDownFcn',@(h,e)opentoline('YourFunctionName.m',LineNumber));
```

In this case, when you click on the figure (not the axis, or any labels, but the grey part of the figure) the m file will open in the editor to the line specified.

If you want to programmatically determine the line number then do the following

```
plot(1:10)
st = dbstack;
set(gcf,'ButtonDownFcn',@(h,e)opentoline(st(1).file,st(1).line-1));
```

Comment: this gonna do it. but is there a way matlab can automatically know 'linenumber'? for instance if the code is modified and the linenumbers change.

Comment: I've added how to get the current line number to the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `undocumented function`:

```
f = figure;
uicontrol ( 'string', 'open "str2double.m" @ 200', 'callback',  @(a,b)opentoline(which('str2double.m'),200), 'position', [100 100 400 50] )
```

It works for me in r2015a