# Is there any alternative for goto-statements in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have a problem with writing a program in MATLAB. I need a goto-statement for solving my problem. Here is the code:

```
for i=1:n
1:  newT=T(i)+unifrnd(-r,r);
    newT=P(i)+unifrnd(-r,r);
    if newT<Tmax && newT>Tmin && newP<Pmax && newP>Pmax
        bestT=newT bestP=newP
    else
        go to 1
    end
end
```

Is there any alternative for that goto-statement?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [matlab GOTO (sort of)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35655101/matlab-goto-sort-of)

Answer (score 1):

Is something like this what you're looking for?

```
for i=1:n
    loop = true;
    while loop
        newT=T(i)+unifrnd(-r,r);
        newT=P(i)+unifrnd(-r,r);
        if newT<Tmax && newT>Tmin && newP<Pmax && newP>Pmax
            bestT=newT bestP=newP
            loop = false;
        end
    end 
end
```

Comment: thank you so much, yes .something like this. I will try it

Answer (score 0):

You can use this submission at MathWorks ® : https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26949-matlab-goto-statement

However, I recommend you to modify your code instead of using that!

Answer (score 0):

you can try switch-case method. Please see example below;

```
caseno = input('input your case no');

switch (caseno)
     case 1
          disp('this first section will run');
     case 2
          disp('this second section will run');
     otherwise
          disp('wrong case no');
end
```